# Regex: match something except within arbitrary delimiters

Tags: ruby, regex

My string:

```
a = "Please match spaces here <but not here>. Again match here <while ignoring these>"
```

Using Ruby's regex flavor, I would like to do something like:

```
a.gsub /regex_pattern/, '_'
```

And obtain:

```
"Please_match_spaces_here_<but not here>._Again_match_here_<while ignoring these>"
```

Comment: You mean this? `/\s+(?![^<]*>)/`

Comment: I think you need non-greedy match, `[^<]*?>`.

Comment: @Alan, you are correct, can you post your solution as the answer?

Comment: @user1934428: The greedy version is correct, but a non-greedy one would be more efficient.  Even better is what I used in my answer: `[<>]*>`.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Given your greedy form, if we have a text of the form `A<B>C<D>E`,  wouldn't it ignore the C part? If C contains spaces, they would be ignored, because after the opening '<' right after A, everything until the closing '>' right after D would be covered by your regexp.

Comment: Sorry, I omitted the `^` in the comment.  It's correct in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
result = subject.gsub(/\s+(?![^<>]*>)/, '_')
```

This regex assumes there's nothing tricky like escaped angle brackets.  Also be aware that `\s` matches newlines, TABs and other whitespace characters as well as spaces.  That's probably what you want, but you have the option of matching only spaces:

```
/ +(?![^<>]*>)/
```

Comment: let me understand: are you saying that the pattern would be simpler if a different delimiter (other than angle brackets) were to be used?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to cover all the bases.  This is actually the simplest scenario.  Parentheses or square brackets would have to be escaped, and non-bracketing delimiters like quotes would require a much more complicated regex.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it works:

```
a = "Please match spaces here <but not here>. Again match here <while ignoring these>"

pattern = /<(?:(?!<).)*>/

a.gsub(pattern, '')
# => "Please match spaces here . Again match here "
```